# tabs is a not a function error in jQuery(Rails)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am getting below error while disable tabs in rails application.tabs is div id.

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).tabs is not a function

```
$(".tabs").tabs("option", "disabled", [0, 1,2]);
```

Comment: did you include jquery and jquery-ui libs?

Comment: yes added in //= require jquery
//= require jquery-ui

Comment: in application.js

Comment: any solution to fix this?